# 物理サーバーへCentOS6を自動インストールしたい

Tags: linux, centos

現在は`kickstart`を利用して数台の物理サーバに対する`CentOS6`インストール作業を半自動化しています。しかし良いデバッグの仕方がわからないために、設定ファイルを更新するたびDVDを焼いてインストールする作業を行っており、1回にだいたい30分ほどかかってしまっています。

より効率が良く、(もし可能なら)検証も容易な方法はありますか？(たとえば`chef`を用いて物理マシンへの`CentOS6`インストールなどを行うなどが可能でしょうか)

仮想マシンの構築は割りとよく記事で見かけるのですが、物理マシンの自動構築方法についてお教えいただけると助かります。`Baremetal Deployment`といったキーワードも耳にするのですが、数台程度の構成には大げさで複雑なのかなと考えてます。

尚、この物理サーバーがローカルネットワーク内の最初のマシンでして、この上に仮想マシンを立ち上げてDNSやDHCP、Webサーバを構築していくことになります。（ただし、物理サーバの構築時だけ一時的にそれらを開発ノートPCなどで用意することは可能かもしれません。)

Answer (score 3):

構築に時間がかかるかもしれませんが、すぐに思いついたのはPXEブート経由でkickstartをつかった自動インストールを行う事です。

もしご存じなければ、PXEブートで～というのは、いわゆるネットワークブートからのインストールです。
この画面でDHCPから指示があれば起動してOSのインストールなどが行えます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

OSのinstallイメージなど必要なリソースはhttpアクセス可能なサーバーに置いておきます。
kickstartのファイルも同じところに置くことになりますので、kickstartのファイルを作り直してもhttpサーバーのファイルを更新するだけで良いので、構築してしまえばDVDの焼き直しよりは効率が良いと思います。

ただし、PXEブート環境を作るのにも（特に最初は）時間がかかります(*1)ので、数台程度だとかえって時間がかかってしまいそうですね。

(*1) PXEブートはDHCPサーバーが指示する格好になるのでDHCPサーバー構築、tftp構築、httpサーバー構築などが必要になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。実はこの物理マシン群がローカルネットワーク内の最初のマシンでして、DHCPサーバはその後に構築されるのです（説明が足りていませんでした。）しかし、回答をいただいてふと思ったのですが、物理サーバー構築の時だけ一時的なDHCPサーバをノートPCなどで立ち上げるのは可能かもしれません。

Comment: @3100 そうですね。特に最終的なDHCPサーバーと同等のOSを用意できれば設定ファイル等も使い回せますし有効だと思います。
私も昔物理メディアが持ち込めない環境で、一時的なDHCPサーバー（特定マシン以外のIPは決定しないPXEBOOT用）を作って凌いだ事があります。
気をつける事は既存DHCPサーバーと競合しない様にする事ですが、既にネットワーク全体の初期構築みたいですのでその心配もなさそうですね。
必要に応じてノートPCの方でIPのリース時間を短くしておけば、各マシンでリース切れになって本物のDHCPサーバーからのIP取得に切り替わってくれて便利かもしれません。（場合によってはリース状況ファイルの移行をせずにリース切れ待ちで凌げるかもしれませんが、それはやったことないので余談ということで）

Answer (score 2):

- ベースのインストールを、kickstartで行う。kickstartの中でchefの設定も入れておく
- インストール後の設定変更はchef経由で行う

という手法ではダメでしょうか？

例えば、下記のks.cfgはどうでしょうか？

- PXEブートではなく、起動時にホスト名、IPアドレスなどを入力する
- インストールに使用するCentOS6の関連ファイルをNFSサーバ 192.168.44.151:/images/cent6に配置
- 追加でインストールしたいファイルを192.168.44.151:/images/work/に配置

```
# Kickstart file automatically generated by anaconda.
#version=DEVEL
install
nfs --server=192.168.44.151 --dir=/images/cent6
lang en_US.UTF-8
keyboard jp106
%include /tmp/network-ks.cfg
rootpw  --plaintext password
firewall --service=ssh
authconfig --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
selinux --enforcing
timezone --utc Asia/Tokyo
zerombr
bootloader --location=partition --driveorder=sda --append="crashkernel=auto"
clearpart --all --drives=sda --initlabel
part /boot/efi --fstype=efi --grow --maxsize=200 --size=50
part /boot --fstype=ext4 --size=500
part pv.vol1 --grow --size=1
volgroup vg_vol1 --pesize=4096 pv.vol1
logvol / --fstype=ext4 --name=lv_root --vgname=vg_vol1 --grow --size=1024 --maxsize=51200
logvol swap --name=lv_swap --vgname=vg_vol1 --grow --size=1638 --maxsize=1638
repo --name="CentOS"  --baseurl=nfs:192.168.44.151:/images/cent6 --cost=100
%packages
@core
@server-policy
@workstation-policy
nfs-utils
%end
%pre --log=/root/anaconda-pre.log
#!/bin/bash
exec < /dev/tty6 > /dev/tty6 2>&1
chvt 6
echo "=== Please input this server information ==="
read -p "Enter hostname: " NEWHOSTNAME
read -p "Enter IP address: " NEWIPADDR
read -p "Enter netmask: " NEWNETMASK
read -p "Enter default gw: " NEWGATEWAY
read -p "Enter DNS server IP: " NEWDNS
echo "network --bootproto=static --ip=${NEWIPADDR} --netmask=${NEWNETMASK} --gateway=${NEWGATEWAY} --nameserver=${NEWDNS} --device=eth0 --onboot=yes --hostname=${NEWHOSTNAME}" > /tmp/network-ks.cfg
chvt 1
%end
%post --log=root/anaconda-post.log --erroronfail
echo "192.168.44.151   master" >> /etc/hosts
mkdir /mnt2
mount -t nfs 192.168.44.151:/images/work /mnt2
rpm -ivh /mnt2/chef-11.12.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
mkdir -p /etc/chef
cp /mnt2/validation.pem /etc/chef/validation.pem
chmod 0600 /etc/chef/validation.pem
cp /mnt2/client.rb /etc/chef/client.rb
/usr/bin/chef-client
%end
#reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

一台目の設定ですと、物理的なメディアを使わざる得ないので、USBかDVDが手っ取り早いと思います。そして、USBの方が、繰り返しには便利だと思います。

まず、イメージ作成環境を用意します。もし、まだ構築していないのでしたら、DVDのイメージを自動生成する環境を作ります。この環境は、別の方が説明されているPXEBOOT用のイメージにも使えますから、一つあると便利と思います。そして、同じイメージ作成環境を用いてUSBに作るようにすれば便利です。

ここから先は色々な方法があると思います。また、パッケージの構成をいじるのが多いとか少ないとか、設定ファイルだけしかかえないと、など条件は色々あると思いますが、*1)ベースになる部分を高速に設定する*ことと、*2)パッケージの追加をすること*、*3)設定ファイルを置き換えること*あたりを区分けして考えると良いかもしれません。

ベース部分は、たとえば、ディスクイメージを作ってUSBに納めておいて、イメージコピーし（あとで必要に応じて、パーティションサイズは変えるなど）、その上にインストールしてゆく方法はとれると思います。その上に, 2), 3) を上書きする。ある程度安定したら 1) に 2), 3) の結果をマージする、というステップをとれば、かなり時間削減できるのではないでしょうか。

もちろん、構築の手間とデバッグはそれなりにかかりますから、手間をかける価値があれば、ですけれども。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かにUSBのが効率良いですよね。また、区分けするという考え方もその通りだと思いました。あれこれ試行錯誤する時にはシェルスクリプトなどで試しておいて、安定してからディスクイメージへ反映させるという方法で、現在よりは短縮できそうです。